# How much VRAM do I need for training a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Hello I recently started my bachelor Project in which I need to train a LSTM model which has following structure

inputs (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 80)]        0

masking (Masking)           (None, None, 80)          0

lstm (LSTM)                 (None, None, 100)         72400

outputs (TimeDistributed)   (None, None, 39)          3939

=================================================================

Total params: 76,339

Trainable params: 76,339

Non-trainable params: 0

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,nb_features), name = 'inputs')
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value = data.MASK_VALUE)(inputs)
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_units,
                             return_sequences = True,
                             dropout = dropout_rate)(x)

    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_skills, activation = 'sigmoid')
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(dense, name = 'outputs')(x)
```

Now my qeustion how much VRAM I need for training. I have a 2080ti with 11GB of VRAM inside my Station and I dont know if that is enough. Maybe there is some helpful site which calculates something like that. I try to find it myself but I dont think that something like that exists yet.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

11GB VRAM should be enough. I have trained a 400K+ parameter model with 3 LSTM layers that easily fits inside my 4GB VRAM. If are using GPU, you can also use Tensorboard profiling to view the memory profile of the model when you start training it. There you can see your peak VRAM usage on the GPU device.

Comment: Thanks for this little orientation point:). Helps me alot. Appreciate it